# Would/Will in "‘What is the probability that if you chose one of these 75 patients at random, their injury will (would) have been caused by crushing?"

Tags: conditional-constructions

From a book titled "Medical Statistics from Scratch":

> [image]

Can we use **would have been caused** instead? Like this:

> Now ask the question, ‘What is the probability that if you chose one of these 75 patients at random, their injury **will have been caused** by crushing?’.

After all, **chose** is in the past tense. We often form conditionals with Past Tense + "would have been".

Or is the fact that the data table is presented to the reader makes **will have been** the only correct option?

Comment: **chose** isn't processed as a simple past tense, but as the backshift because of **If**. It is semantically equivalent to **were to choose**. The injury is a given. The result of the condition (the randomness of the selection) is the probability of the cause of definite injury. *If you were to choose an injured patient at random, what is the probability that their injury will have been caused by crushing?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes you can use "would".

However in this case you are talking about *actual* and not *hypothetical* victims of accidents.  If you select one at random the victim **will** have had some kind of injury -- there is no question.

So "will" is better suited for this, as it seems to be [First Conditional and not Third Conditional.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/Grammar/conditional2.htm)